# Encoding problem using osmtogeojson in command line

Tags: json, openstreetmap, geojson

I need to get from the openstreetmap database a quite big dataset (hence I cannot use overpass turbo or JOSM). So I need to go from a json or xml osm file to a geojson one. When I use osmtogeojson on a single point everything's fine (I can export it on Mapbox) However relations doesn't seem to work properly and I also have encoding errors (I hope this is one only problem).

I tried from a test query (`[out:xml];(rel(6928969);>;);out;`), I downloaded both geojson already "translated" from overpass and the osm data for the same results, and then I used osmtogeojson on it. But I couldn't find any encoding to have the same result when I open the file ( it's readable but every "é" is now a "├®"... and this is maybe why there is a problem with mapbox when I'm re-saving this file under UTF-8). Do someone know how I should open the file before saving it to proper UTF-8 (If I don't mapbox doesn't recognize the filetype at all...) ?

Comment: The result should already use UTF-8. Are you sure this isn't a problem with your text editor?

Comment: I've tried to open the files either with Sublime text or with windows notepad, and I always get the same results : the directly downloaded data from overpass turbo (either xml, json or geojson for comparaison) is OK, but after passing through osmtogsojson, I always have this problem...

Comment: Looks like there is already a related issue: https://github.com/tyrasd/osmtogeojson/issues/102. I suggest to describe your problem at this issue. Maybe the developers have time to fix it.

Comment: Alternatively try to convert the resulting file from UTF-16 to UTF-8: `iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 in.txt > out.txt`

Comment: Well I'm on windows so I don't know exactly how to do that but with Sublime Text I have an option to re-open the file with other encodings. I tried UTF-16 but nothing changes... but I'm not sure it's the right thing to do. And yes it seems to be the same issue thank you